# Typescript function type has no effect

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following function type:

```
type functionType = (x:number) => void
```

and the following function

```
const fn : functionType = () => {
  return 1
}
```

I **would** expect Typescript to give me two errors.

1. `fn()` should take a number as a parameter, but you did not provide anything
2. `fn()` is void and can't return a number

However, I get no errors.

Can someone explain this behavior please?

Comment: [Explanation for 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) and [Explanation for 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void), from the TS documentation.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer (after searching for duplicates, which there probably are).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, jcalz. That fully addresses my question :)